# How can i return null or nothing, if the Entity i am checking for ID does not exist, (if i send in an ID of a nonexistant entity)

Tags: c#, loops, object, monogame, chaining

```
entityManager.AddEntity(kat);
entityManager.AddEntity(kai);
entityManager.AddEntity(yugo);
entityManager.AddEntity(tsuki);
entityManager.AddEntity(ryo);
entityManager.AddEntity(nami);
entityManager.AddEntity(yugito);
entityManager.GetEntityWithUniqueId(idToCheck).isActive = false;
```

This is where I use the `GetEntityWithUniqueID(IdToCheck)` method
`IdToCheck` is an integer that is set to 7, and the only entities that exist have an id from 0 to 6.

`IsActive` is a Boolean that exists in entity that will decide if the entity is being "Active".

```
public Entity GetEntityWithUniqueId(int idOfEntity)
        {
            Entity stepEntity;
            Entity returnEntity;

            stepEntity = firstEntity.nextEntity;
            if (firstEntity.uniqueID == idOfEntity)
            {
                returnEntity = firstEntity;
            }
            else
            {
                while (stepEntity.uniqueID != idOfEntity)
                {
                    stepEntity = stepEntity.nextEntity;
                }
                returnEntity = stepEntity;
            }
            return returnEntity;
        }
```

This is my method for checking which entity the ID I send to the method, corresponds to.
This method returns the object Entity I then want to edit.

```
        public void AddEntity(Entity entityToAdd)
        {
            Entity stepEntity;

            if (firstEntity == null)
            {
                firstEntity = entityToAdd;
                firstEntity.uniqueID = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                stepEntity = firstEntity;
                int newID = 1;

                while (stepEntity.nextEntity != null)
                {
                    stepEntity = stepEntity.nextEntity;
                    newID++;
                }
                stepEntity.nextEntity = entityToAdd;
                entityToAdd.uniqueID = newID;
            }
            Debug.Print(entityToAdd + " Has been loaded");
        }
```

This is the method I use to add entities to an object chain, by using an object within Entity that is called `nextEntity`.

Lastly, I get an error if the integer `idOfEntity` is set to an id of an entity that does not exist, I want to fix this so that nothing happens if I send in an id of a nonexistent Entity.

Pastebin links ↓

[Game1 Class where I call my methods to change enteties](https://pastebin.com/eC3qaM9R)

[EntityManager Class where I manage my enteties](https://pastebin.com/782BwM5t)

[Entity Class where I define my enteties](https://pastebin.com/3LryJ27R)

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Comment: Can you just use `return null;` if it needs to return null? Or you can use `if (IdToCheck != null)` before the `GetEntityWithUniqueID(IdToCheck)` method

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting? (Update your answer if possible).